# AWS - share business logic (jar) across multiple lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a smaller application, but it uses multiple lambda functions (20+) for different tasks. Each lambda is it's own java project.
Most of the logic code resides in a jar-file (single project) which is shared among them.

So when making changes to the logic code I need to re-deploy every lambda so they all run the same code base...

Is it possible to point out a S3 bucket path (environment variable) and let my lambdas include the jar as they are run? In that case I only need to re-deploy the logic code.

Or is AWS Code Pipeline the way to go? I have never used that before

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of a scenario, it is better to set up a strong CI/CD pipeline which is able to automate the deployments, so that if you update the library, you are able to update the Lambdas. Using AWS Code Pipeline is just an option.

The problem in using S3 to store the Jar and download (to /tmp folder in Lambda) it upon execution is that it will affect the application performance even if you download it and execute the code with reflection.

Comment: Ok I will look into the CI/CD pipeline. I have my code in aws code commit. As a sidenote, I didn't even know that Lambdas had a /tmp folder